# Bootstrap 4 li tags not aligning as block elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

According to http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html `li` is a block element if I use `li` tags the menu stays horizontal on toggle on small device in Bootstrap 4. My question is if `li` tag is a block element then the result should be vertical menu for the code below instead of horizontal?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
    </li> 
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another Menu</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Its horizontal for desktop, vertical for phone. https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/3/

Comment: I'm getting horizontal for desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Bootstrap 4 is in the alpha stage, which means that the SCSS / CSS for the navbar is not ready yet.

You should add the SCSS code to undo the `float:left` for smaller screens yourself.

You can use the following SCSS code:

```
.navbar {

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    .navbar-brand,
    .nav-item {
      float: none;
    }
  }
}
```

The preceding SCSS compiles into CSS as follows:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-brand,
  .navbar .nav-item {
    float: none;
  }
}
```